# How to create login page on chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I have been working on a chrome extension for several weeks now, however, I am wondering how to go about creating a login page that gains access to the actual extension.

So I have a chrome extension and I have also made a wix website for the extension, where someone can sign up and create an account. The user will use that account info to sign into the chrome extension login page?

Questions:

1: How to create a login page that determines who can access the chrome extensions contents?

2: How to link the chrome extension to my websites member info?

Comment: You'll need an API with a database that you can call.

Comment: I am pretty new javascript and am little confused on how to link a database to both my wix website and chrome extension. Do you know how to?